# HSQLDB/Oracle rownum difference

Tags: oracle, hsqldb

The following query doesn't result in the same answer on HSQLDB (2.3.1 with ORA syntax support set to true) as it does on Oracle.

`select max(ID) from (select ID from TRANSACTION where LOAD=2 and ID>=4 order by ID asc) where rownum <=2`

Applied to the following dataset

```
<dataset>
<TRANSACTION ID="2" LOAD="1" />
<TRANSACTION ID="3" LOAD="1" />
<TRANSACTION ID="4" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="5" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="6" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="7" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="8" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="10" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="11" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="12" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="13" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="14" LOAD="2" />
<TRANSACTION ID="15" LOAD="2" />
</dataset>
```

Oracle returns `5` but HSQLDB reports `15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference here which may be changed in a future version of HSQLDB.